# Config for nginx for Polycom provisioning

Tags: nginx, voip, provisioning, polycom

Good day

Does anyone have a working nginx config for HTTPS provisioning of Polycom VX411 phones?

Provision is working via HTTP. HTTPs with any settings (TLS1 to 1.3, same on the phone) give no SSL handshake stage completed.

The certificate is okay, certbot, single domain.

Firmware is 6.4.5

Comment: Don't know these devices but would dumping tcp traffic give any insight into what's going on?  Or is that how you know it's failing during handshake...

Comment: It is tls. Dumping traffic give same, error on handshake. And I not see what is not okay from polycom side, just able see handshake failed

Comment: I also checkef nginx debug for ssl